# Command line to build C++ program with LLVM libs

Tags: g++, llvm, clang++

I am starting in the world of LLVM and searched in several places and read several documentation about LLVM but I found nothing showing how to compile a program that uses LLVM headers and libs ....
I wrote this simple program just to try to compile, using the Visual Studio cross-compiler, I tried several command line options .... even using the -lLLVM option, but, nothing worked ...

I tried using g++ and clang++

```
#include <iostream>

#include <llvm/ADT/OwningPtr.h>
#include <llvm/Support/MemoryBuffer.h>

int main()
{
        llvm::OwningPtr<llvm::MemoryBuffer> buffer

        return 0;
}
```

When I try to build, I get this erro:

```
error : 'llvm/ADT/OwningPtr.h' file not found
```

So, what is the command line to compile this simple program?

Answer (score 0):

The command   `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` will provide you with all the linkable llvm libraries, provided you have llvm installed. Just link with this command in single quotes